# Comparing values in different columns - looping

Tags: vba, excel

I want to compare values from

EntryP:

6

11

4

TwndHigh:

5

10

4

6

10

11

I want to compare each value in EntryP to the values in TwndHigh and find the first value in TwndHigh that is bigger than EntryP. For eg the first value that is bigger than 6 is 10, **and the first value that is bigger than 4 is 6.** that means i want my row number in TwndHigh to match the row of EntryP i want to compare.

```
Sub BUYexitGAIN()

Dim ohlc As Range
Dim cll, cell, twndhigh, twndlow As Range
Dim stoplossb, entrypriceb, stoplosss, entryprices As Double
Dim exitgains, exitlosss, exitgainb, exitlossb As Range
Dim n As Range
Dim i As Long


For i = 990 To 2000

'BUY
    If Range("M" & i).Value = "buy" Then
        entrypriceb = Range("w" & i)
        Set twndlow = Range("K" & i & ":" & "K10000")

    For Each cell In twndlow
        If cell.Value > entrypriceb Then
            Range("z" & cell.Row) = cell.Value
            Range("t" & cell.Row) = -Range("t" & i)
            Range("u" & cell.Row) = Range("t" & i) * cell.Value * 10000
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell
End If

Next i
End Sub
```

A bit messy right now, but I'm using double loops (For and For each cell). This gives me about 3 values in my return columns (when i only want the first value that meets my condition), with 2 of them usually as wrong values and 1 of them right. How do I make my code a single loop, or make it just return the First Value I want? Thanks guys

*PS sorry i know i have asked similar questions but I wanted to rewrite my whole question to make it easier for you guys.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've included code below to solve the problem you stated at the top. If you have EntryP in A1:A3 and TwndHigh in A5:A10 as in the example it will output the results next to the EntryP data. Based on your example data you are dealing with relatively small integers, please note you need to initialise possibleResult to something larger than your expected input data and you may need to change the data type to accomdate this.

```
Public Sub FindFirstHigher()

Dim possibleResult As Integer

Dim EntryP, TwndHigh As Range

Set EntryP = Worksheets("firstHigher").Range("A1:A3")
Set TwndHigh = Worksheets("firstHigher").Range("A5:A10")

For Each entrycell In EntryP

    possibleResult = 9999

    For Each checkcell In TwndHigh

        If (checkcell.Value > entrycell.Value And checkcell.Value < possibleResult) Then

            possibleResult = checkcell.Value

        End If

    Next checkcell

    entrycell.Offset(0, 1).Value = possibleResult

Next entrycell

End Sub
```